# Replace 0 in one field in case statement result that is stringing fields

Tags: sql, replace, case

I have a statement like the following:

```
select distinct s.field1, s.field 2, 

Case when s.intfield3 = 2018 then (RTRIM(cast(s.intfield4 as char (2))) +'/1/'+ cast(s.intfield3 as char (4)))

when c.intfield3 = 2018 then (RTRIM(cast(c.intfield4 as char(2))) +'/1/'+ cast(c.intfield3 as char (4)))
End as newfield
```

My issue is s.intfield4 & c.intfield4 have some 0 values.  I need to change those 0 values to a 12.  I've tried a few things, but nothing is working.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
case when x = 0 then 12 else x end
```

Comment: Where would I put it in that long string of trimming and casting and stringing fields and characters?  It's already in a Case statement.

Comment: @PurpleCyn . . . "My issue is s.intfield4 & c.intfield4 have some 0 values. I need to change those 0 values to a 12."  I believe this answers your question.

Comment: I was over thinking it!  Thank you!

Comment: For others that follow, and over think it too:
select distinct s.field1, s.field 2, 

Case when s.intfield3 = 2018 and s.intfield4 > 0 then (RTRIM(cast(s.intfield4 as char (2))) +'/1/'+ cast(s.intfield3 as char (4)))
when s.intfield3 = 2018 and s.intfield4 = 0 then ('12/1/'+ cast(s.intfield3 as char (4)))

etc....